# Android: Is it impossible to have a mixed screen with listview element?

Tags: listview, android-layout

may be a layout file can explain what I am talking about

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" />



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sublayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_btn1"
    android:onClick="select" />


  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_btn2"
    android:onClick="select2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you see linearlayout act as the root layout element

and what i want is a listview for 80% of the screen, the next 20% of screen will be make up with other elements, for example, button. Is it impossible to do so in android?If so, which attribute should I work on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the solution is using `android:layout_weight`, so you can specify a size ratio between multiple views.
Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="80"/>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sublayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="20">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_btn1"
    android:onClick="select" />


 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_btn2"
    android:onClick="select2" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```